# How to save from JTable to CSV or Excel?

Tags: java, csv, swing, jtable, export-to-csv

Is there a way to save `JTable` data to excel? I would like to save the data that I input from the program, from the table and then to a CSV file.

I would like to have it so that there is a button that will then save the inputted data from the GUI into the table and then to the CSV file.

Comment: I would like to have it so that there is a button that will then save the inputted data from the jform into the jtable and then to the CSV file.

Comment: The fact that you used Eclipse for this is mostly irrelevant. That's just the IDE. Also please edit your question if you've got details to add instead of posting a comment.

Comment: sorry fairly new to this website. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you:-

Method to write to a csv file.

```
public static void exportToCSV(JTable table,
        String path) {

    try {

        TableModel model = table.getModel();
        FileWriter csv = new FileWriter(new File(path));

        for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            csv.write(model.getColumnName(i) + ",");
        }

        csv.write("\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                csv.write(model.getValueAt(i, j).toString() + ",");
            }
            csv.write("\n");
        }

        csv.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("Error "+e);
    }
}
```

For reading and showing it to a JTable you can use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file.csv")); 
List list = reader.readAll();
JTable table = new JTable(list.toArray());
```

Comment: I'd be wary of writing CSV that way, as any text containing a `,` will break it.  I'd have simply encouraged the use of OpenCSV to write it as well

Comment: Even withouth OpenCSV it does not look too bad to me. Yes, quoting all fields would avoid the problem of un-quoted "," breaking stuff, but introduce a need for double-quoting quotes -- on the other hand, OP may have very simple requirements, and this is definitely a step in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'magic function' of a JTable that I know of that will do this. JTable is a UI component, and what you're asking for is a data function, not a user interface function. And it doesn't have much to do with eclipse, which is just the IDE one uses to write the code.

I think what you may be looking for is the *model* on which the JTable is based. The first solution that occurs to me is to alter that model code to have a method that will write out the data in the format you want; then a(nother) button on your UI would invoke this method on the model to write out the data when the user chooses. There are likely other ways you might get this done, but that seems the most straightforward and easiest.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this code:

```
public static boolean convertToCSV(JTable table,
                                   String path) {
try {
    TableModel model = table.getModel();
    FileWriter csv = new FileWriter(new File(path));

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        csv.write(model.getColumnName(i) + ",");
    }
    csv.write("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            csv.write(model.getValueAt(i, j).toString() + ",");
        }
        csv.write("\n");
    }
    csv.close();
    return true;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: A code-only answer is not very helpful.  Answers require an explanation as to why the code you're presenting is better at solving the problem than the code the OP posted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: (1-) this answer is no different than the already accepted answer.